# Spring Boot java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor size

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

currently I am testing my Spring Boot app, which is a rest service with a circuit breaker pattern. Now
I called my service with 20 threads at the same time and get the following log entry:

```
Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@127adac1[Not completed, task = java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter@74bf28cd[Wrapped task = null]] rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@19ae13b2[Running, pool size = 10, active threads = 10, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 16]
```

So my question would be is the maximum size of the thread pool realy 10 and am I able to set it to somthing differen?

I found the propertie `server.tomcat.max-threads` and set it to 10 all request will pass.

**Edit**

I am calling another rest service with the Spring Boot Resttemplate could this one cause the problem?

```
    @HystrixCommand(
        commandKey = "callRestService", fallbackMethod = "failCallRestService", ignoreExceptions = DataNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<DataAtomsResponse> callRestService(String searchItem, String trackingId)
        throws RestServiceNotAvailableException
    {
        ThreadContext.put("trackingID", trackingId);
        configureRestTemplate();
        LOGGER.info("Received request with trackingId: {}", trackingId);
        Map<String, String> restUrlParams = new HashMap<>();
        restUrlParams.put(REST_URL_PARAMETER, searchItem);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = getRestParameters(trackingId);

        DataAtomsResponse dataAtomsResponse;
        LOGGER.info("Request RestService trackingID: {}", trackingId);
        ResponseEntity<String> dataResponse=
            restTemplate.exchange(config.getRestServiceUrl(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class, restUrlParams);

        if (dataResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK || dataResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) {
            LOGGER.debug("Transform result from RestService to JSON trackingID: {}", trackingId);
            dataAtomsResponse = dataParser.parse(dataResponse.getBody(), searchItem, trackingId);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(dataAtomsResponse );
        }
        else {
            throw new RestServiceNotAvailableException(dataResponse.getStatusCode().getReasonPhrase());
        }
    }
```

I have not implemented any ThreadPoolExecuter in any other class.

Comment: It is hard to know what exactly is your problem. I would suggest to post your code who sets up your ThreadPoolExecutor and how you are using it. The Java API on ThreadPoolExecutor is really good. Make sure you understand how use it as this class is highly customizable.

Comment: Re, "I called it with 20 threads..." Not sure what "it" is, but if "it" is an `ExecutorService` then, you do not call it with threads. The objects that you submit to an executor service are _tasks,_ and the executor service uses its own _worker threads_ to perform/execute your tasks.

Comment: First of all thank you for your help. ChaudPain I think I  am not implemented any ThreadPoolExecutor but let me check it. Solomon it means my service in and I am testing it with jmeter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the problem.
Histrix uses the normal java ThreadPoolExecutor and the value of maximum threads is set to 10. This https://medium.com/@truongminhtriet96/playing-with-hystrix-thread-pool-c7eebb5b0ddc article helped me alot. So I set these configs

````
hystrix.threadpool.default.maximumSize=32
hystrix.threadpool.default.allowMaximumSizeToDivergeFromCoreSize=true
server.tomcat.max-threads=32```
````